# Facebook login cannot be achieved when facebook app is installed

Tags: android, facebook-login

We are using Facebook login in our app. when we logged in to the app locally it logged in correctly and created the release key and updated it in the Facebook developers page and uploaded in the google play. When downloading it from the google play we logged in using the offical Facebook app. It says that

> No android Keyhash for the app configured. Please configure the
>   keyhash in the developers page.

But when we uninstalled the official Facebook app and repeated for the login it works fine.

Thanks in Advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

Please add hash key of both release & debug key into facebook app and make sure your facebook app is published.

You can use following command on bash to generate key hash

> keytool -exportcert -alias  -keystore
>    | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

for more visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash